How to use ffmpeg to detect clipping
What is the right way to use ffmpeg to print samples that are clipping? Is there something better than this?
-af aeval='if(gte(abs(val(ch)),0.9999),print(n))'

which prints the sample number whenever any channel's sample (after being converted into a double) is greater than 0.9999 or less than -0.9999. The reason I can't use eq(abs(val(ch)),1) is because clipped samples are not -1 to 1, but -1 to 0.999969 (for s16). I guess aeval automatically converts the input to a double-precision floating point even if the input is s16 so I can't use the negation of between(val(ch),-32768,32727) to detect clipping.
If it prints the way I want then I can assume that multiple peaking samples in a short duration are a clipping event.
